# L,R=301,NC is this correct

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

Is this 301 correct ? [L,R=301,NC]

We have so many back links going to urls in the old site and trying to keep the for seo benefit, but the site has still dropped in rankings despite trying to keep them all clean and going to their corresponding urls in the new site. I just want to check we have this done correctly with the [L,R=301,NC]

```
    RewriteRule ^section.php/178/1/small-shrubs/?$ http://www.gardenbuilders.co.uk/section/127/1/garden-planting [L,R=301,NC]
```

http://www.gardenbuilders.co.uk/section.php/178/1/small-shrubs/

Many thanks

Comment: Do you know what those flags mean? That doesn't really have anything to do with your ranking except  using a 301 Redirect which you are doing. There is something else that caused your rank to go down.

Comment: No i'm not sure what they mean. I assumed they were permanent url change.